# Confused about an outlet

Tags: electrical

Outlet worked fine for years.  It stopped working...changed with new one (wired just as the other was, Black to gold, White to silver, Ground to green).  Nothing.  Nothing Hot to Neutral, nothing (2v) Hot to Ground, 122v Neutral to Ground (both in outlet and wires without.  This is on same leg as three other lights, all of which still work, breaker not tripped.  Help

Comment: Are there any GFCI outlets in the room or close by?

Comment: Were there 2 black wires or only one? Was the old recep wired with backstabs?

Comment: One black, one white (both in back), and the ground.  I put then on the screws of the new fixture.  There are a few junction boxes in attic, all seem good, tightened fittings on lights and light switches on others.  Cannot figure this out.  When I turn off breaker, nothing else turns off but the lights and outlet I mentioned.

Comment: No GFI or GFCI. Could it be a hidden junction box with loose wire?  Don't understand no power between hit and neutral

Comment: Where are these outlets?  garage, bathroom?

Comment: They were in the original garage (built in 1972).  It's been converted to an in law apt.  Those additions are all on their own breakers.  The two outlets are also controlling a light in living room and laundry room (a three way).  All switches look good, as do the three lights...unless I've missed a junction in attic underneath insulation

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this hundreds of times. The problem is almost always in the first non-working outlet or the last working one! The very few that this has not been the case it has been in a junction box or breaker panel very rare!

Go to the last working outlet--it may be a bad back stab feeding to the next outlet (quite common) or a broken wire usually because of a nick where the wire was stripped. Again, rare, but a possibility.

Comment: You should get a plug in tester with the 3 lights on it to help. It sounds like you may also have a reversed hot & neutral, likely at one of the previous outlets or junction boxes.

Comment: I will try the other outlet (there is another, just found it...it's not working either (same condition as the first)).  Ugg.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @scott ,the op has the receptacle properly wired according to the standard color code, also since the op took voltage measurements a plug in tested would be a waste of $.  As I said in my answer I have seen this so many times on backstabs it is almost a joke to me. I gave a co worker the exact same advice last week he was amazed I could troubleshoot it down to 2 receptacles with less information than this question provides. Just remembered to upvote the question since it had enough info, but the plug in testers are referred as magic 8 ball testers by some on this site and I agree.

Comment: Ok, changed the other outlet on this circuit.  Neither work (Hot to Neutral is minimal volts, Both Hot to Ground and Neutral to Ground yield 120 volts...in both outlets on both receptacles).  Again, lights work.  Now what?  Ps.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just found a light switch was using back stabs (as were the two outlets I changed out).  I put all those associated wires on the correct screws.  This switch was a three way.  Cannot access the other switch (it's behind the furnace).  Waiting for tenant to let me know if outlets are working.  Ill be back with an answer.

Comment: Not working....ugg

Comment: Still dead hot to Neutral, 120volts Both Hot to Ground and Neutral to Ground

Comment: Since you have working lights on the same breaker and no voltage hot to ground or neutral you know it is the black wire. Since you have found back stabs in use I would be tracking down every outlet between the breaker panel and the non working or last working outlet. It may be in a different room that has a common wall many times I use 1 run to feed 2 rooms. Any junction boxes should be accessible, you might have luck tracing the wires using a stud finder with a voltage alert, I have done this when I did not have my professional tracer, they are not real accurate but may help you track them.

Comment: I have 120volts BOTH Hot to Ground and Neutral to Ground, just not Hot to Neutral

Comment: I mis read the last sentence, but with nothing hot to neutral and nothing hot to ground I don’t see how you could have 120 ground to neutral, even if mis wired neutral and ground connect to a common point back in the panel unless you are reading phantom voltages, plug in a lamp or some kind of load and see what the voltages do , I still think it could be a bad back stab between the outlet and the panel from the info we have.

Comment: I am just as confused.  Thanks.  All back stabs have been swapped with new using screws (with the exception of one I cannot access).  Same issue